# Cannot pickle a Naive Bayes classifier in Python?

Tags: python, text, nltk, pickle, text-classification

I am trying to save my trained Naive Bayes classifier in python. I've followed previous, similar questions to no avail. I'm kind of new to Python and don't really understand what is wrong, I've created and trained my classifier as per the NLTK book. How can I save this model to work on it later?

This is the error I've been stuck with:

```
picklingError: Can't pickle <class 'generator'>: attribute lookup generator on builtin failed
```

Currently I have:

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
saveClassifier(classifier)

def saveClassifier(classifier):
        with open('cp_model.pkl', 'w') as f:
            dump(classifier, f)
```

Any help at all would be appreciated, I've literally been trying to fix this for hours.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
I experimented a bit with this and I concluded that your code works perfectly when tried with the latest stable version of nltk on a valid dataset.
So I would suggest you either update/reinstall your library or check that your dataset is a valid one.
A valid dataset has to be a list of tuples `(featureset,label)`.

Comment: "For picke you should also write as a binary file 'wb'" - not necessary: *"By default, the pickle data format uses a printable ASCII representation. "*

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've attempted to implement your fix, but I've only ever used classifiers as they are used in the book. How can I get the probdist of the labels/features prior to training?

Comment: you are actually doing it right, my bad, I am used to scikit learn way to do this. I tried a bit and edited my answer.